# Thread Executor - beginner

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have two classes. In class `A`, I have the `run()` method looped forever, while in the class `B`, i have the threadpool.

My question is, From Class `B`, how can I control and stop the thread executing `run()` method in class `A` , I have tried forceshutdown, `threadExecutor.shutdownNow()`, But it isnt working.
The loop seems to go on forever.

Here is example piece of code:

---

```
public class A implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Hi");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int noOfThreads = 1;
        A ThreadTaskOne = new A();
        System.out.println("Threads are being started from Class B");
        ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);
        threadExecutor.execute(ThreadTaskOne);
        threadExecutor.shutdownNow();
        System.out.println("B Ends, no of threads that are alive : " + Thread.activeCount());
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some of your code so that we can see what's going on.

Comment: Thread `A` needs to play nice and pay attention to the `interrupted` state.  Have a look at [`Thread#isInterrupted`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29)

Comment: Change while(true) to while (!Thread.isInterrupted()) to see what happens.  (as noted in my answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MadProgammer said, your "infinite" loop needs to pay attention to Thread.isInterrupted.  e.g.  (very schematic)

```
public void run() {

   while (!Thread.isInterrupted()) {
      doSomethinginTheLoop1();
      blah...blah...blah
      // if the loop is very long you might want to check isInterrupted 
      // multiple times for quicker termination response
      doSomethingInTheLoop2();
   }

   // now, here's a decision of what you do
   // do you throw an InterruptedException or trust others to check interrupted flag.
   // read Java COncurrency in Practice or similar...
}
```

Comment: @user1751634: Then why do you have "But it isnt working. The loop seems to go on forever." in your question? Aren't you contradicting your OP with your comment here?

Comment: @BheshGurung .. It did work.. It was my programming error..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on [`ExecutorService#shutdownNow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29) says -

> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.

And your thread doesn't seem to care if it has been interrupted.

So check if it has been interrupted

```
while (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
```

instead of just doing

```
while (true)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be below is useful for you.

```
public static class A implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println("Hi");
        }
    }
}
```